# Better Way for Crushing Coconut into 500 mesh Coal for Carbonization

Tags: physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, materials, physical-organic-chemistry

I am planning to use coconut as a raw material for carbonization, but I need to crush it into 500 mesh coal. Currently, I am using a mortar and pestle to grind the coconut shell into a fine powder, but the process is very time-consuming and the yield is not always consistent. Imagine half a day crushing it, and yet I only acquire 2 grams.

I am looking for a better method to crush coconut into 500 mesh coal. I have heard about using ball mills or other grinding equipment, but I am not sure which one is suitable for this purpose. For mixing with PVA for nanofiber material.

Can anyone suggest a better and more efficient method for crushing coconut into 500 mesh coal for carbonization? And what type of equipment should I use for this process? I appreciate any other suggestions or tips on how to improve the yield and consistency of the coal.

Comment: You will probably need a commercial grade mill/grinder. Please do not waste your days by using a mortar and pestle. Is this an academic project?

Comment: A hammer mill would be logical first step . There are a variety of grinding type machines ; likely depends more on what is available or how much one is willing to spend.

Comment: Do you need 500 mesh coconut shell or 500 mesh coconut coal? As the question is unclear in this. Crushing coal could be easier than crushing shells. Crushing coconut shells leads to coal only if it is intensive enough to cause carbonization.

Comment: Agree with @Poutnik. Carbonize first.  Then, if you like, reconstitute to desired size and you have ... charcoal briquettes!

Comment: @Poutnik 500 mesh of coal that was processed coconut. It is not coconut shell

Comment: The question formulation is misleading. Why not to carbonize first, crush after?

Comment: i am Sorry I gonna fix my title and create new question instead